Matrix Like Grid Compatible With d3.js and Row Transition Effects
I have a grid design with several rows and 3 columns. The rows represent something like a folder structure, that is there is a parent with some child, who also can have some childs and so on.
Eventually I want to create a collapsible design, i.e. when clicking on a parent all of its children are shown and a aconsequent click hides those children again.
While I have no problems adding rows to the design, I have quite some difficulties to animate the addition of the rows.
In the toy example below you see that the rows appear instantaneously, but I'd like them to ease in.
Any ideas? (I am rather flexible on the grid and css, so if there is another way of organising the data, I'd ber very happy to adapt).
P.S.: I toyed with 2 different grid designs (display: contents and subgrid and while the latter seems to be the canonical way of getting a matrix like structure, I had no luck of forcing the structure to use the same width for the seocnd column, so any hints on this side-problem are welcome as well.


function update(data) {
  const rows = d3.selectAll('.grid_container')
    .selectAll('div')
    .data(data, (d) => d.id)
    .join('div')
    .classed('row', true);
  rows.each(function (d, i) {
    const enter = d3.select(this);
    enter.selectAll('div')
      .data(d.content)
      .join('div')
      .text((d) => d);
  })
  
  
}

function genRow(i) {
  return {
    id: i,
    content: [...Array(3)].map((_, j) => i == 0 & j == 1 ?
        'Super Long Line' : 'Cell ' + (i + 1) + '/' + (j + 1))
  }
}

function addRow() {
  data.push(genRow(data.length));
  update(data);
}

const data = [...Array(2)].map((_, i) => genRow(i));
 
update(data);
#contents {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 110px max-content auto;
  grid-auto-rows: 1fr;
  gap: 5px;
 }
 
 #subgrid {
   display: grid;
   row-gap: 5px;
   grid-auto-rows: 1fr;
 }
 
 #subgrid > .row {
   display: grid;
   grid-template-columns: 110px max-content auto;
   column-gap: 5px;
 }
 
 .row {
   display: contents;
 }
 
 .row > div {
   padding: 10px;
 }
 
 .row:nth-child(odd) > div {
   background-color: forestgreen;
 }
 
 .row:nth-child(even) > div {
   background-color: purple;
 }
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/7.8.5/d3.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="addRow()">Add Row</button>

<h1><code>display:contents</code></h1>
<div id="contents" class="grid_container">
</div>

<h1><code>subgrid</code></h1>
<div id="subgrid" class="grid_container">
</div>




You are looking for d3.transition (docs here).
Here's a quick example with your code:


function update(data) {
  const rows = d3.selectAll('.grid_container')
    .selectAll('div')
    .data(data, (d) => d.id)
    .enter() // <-- changed this to just enter selection so existing rows to re-fade in
    .append('div')
    .classed('row', true);
    
  rows.each(function (d, i) {
    const enter = d3.select(this);
    enter.selectAll('div')
      .data(d.content)
      .join('div')
      .style('opacity', 0)
      .transition()
      .duration(1000)
      .style('opacity', 1)
      .text((d) => d);
  })
  
  
}

function genRow(i) {
  return {
    id: i,
    content: [...Array(3)].map((_, j) => i == 0 & j == 1 ?
        'Super Long Line' : 'Cell ' + (i + 1) + '/' + (j + 1))
  }
}

function addRow() {
  data.push(genRow(data.length));
  update(data);
}

const data = [...Array(2)].map((_, i) => genRow(i));
 
update(data);
#contents {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 110px max-content auto;
  grid-auto-rows: 1fr;
  gap: 5px;
 }
 
 #subgrid {
   display: grid;
   row-gap: 5px;
   grid-auto-rows: 1fr;
 }
 
 #subgrid > .row {
   display: grid;
   grid-template-columns: 110px max-content auto;
   column-gap: 5px;
 }
 
 .row {
   display: contents;
 }
 
 .row > div {
   padding: 10px;
 }
 
 .row:nth-child(odd) > div {
   background-color: forestgreen;
 }
 
 .row:nth-child(even) > div {
   background-color: purple;
 }
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/7.8.5/d3.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="addRow()">Add Row</button>

<h1><code>display:contents</code></h1>
<div id="contents" class="grid_container">
</div>

<h1><code>subgrid</code></h1>
<div id="subgrid" class="grid_container">
</div>




Thanks, will accept this answer. I was, however, not quiet clear that I would like to have a collapse transition instead of a fade. But your answer gave me some ideas. Thanks again!
